# user_login_block doesn't display message

Tags: forms, users

I have created an installation profile.
On one page i have added block using `user_login_block` form.

Now on the page there are other blocks also present.

Now when i submit the form without username and password, it should show me the form error, but it shows this message on next page reload.

I have checked `$message` variable is printed on the page also.

When i write any wrong password and try to login it will not show wrong username password message at that time, but when i reload the page second time at that time message will appear.

Has anyone faced such kind of situation. ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully managed and fix it.
The code i was using to display the login block was as below

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block'));
```

This block used to generate the login block for the login functionality.

Now i tried to render the messages using [theme_status_messages()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7) function.

To fix the issue i created a function in my **template.php** file named **THEMENAME_get_login_block()**.

In this function i added the `theme_status_messages()` function for the displaying the messages. So my function looked like given below.

```
function THEMENAME_get_login_block() {
    $form = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block'));
    $messages = theme_status_messages();
    return $form.$messages;
}
```

And to render the block i used `print THEMENAME_get_login_block();`

This solved my problem. But still i am curious to know the root cause of such kind of events.
Any suggestions are welcomed....